# MongoDB aggregation: count appearances of each value of a field per id

Tags: mongodb

Data example:

```
{ id: 1, field: a, .. }
{ id: 1, field: a, .. }
{ id: 1, field: b, .. }
{ id: 2, field: b, .. }
```

Desired result:

```
{ id: 1, countA: 2, countB: 1 }
{ id :2, countA:0, countB: 1 }
```

'field' is an enum, so I know all the values in advance and can give names to the counters.

I have a solution but it seems that there is a better one. My solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 { $group: { _id: { id: "$id", field: "$field"}, count: { $sum : 1}}},
 { $project: { 
     _id: 1, 
     countA: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$_id.field", "a"] }, then: "$count", else: 0 }},
     countB: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$_id.field", "b"] }, then: "$count", else: 0 }}
    }
 },
 { $group: 
   {_id: "$_id.id", countA: { $max: "$countA"}, countB: { $max :"$countB"}}
 }
])
```

upd: I have a better solution - placing the project before grouping in some way and no need for 2 groupings, but it uses the same principle. But it still seems that there should be somehting more built-in for this purpose

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need one [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to acheive what you want.

Just use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the number of fields with value a and B with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      id: {
        $first: "$id"
      },
      countA: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [ "$field","a"] },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      countB: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [ "$field", "b"] },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Have a look at this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OK--3ShITxZ) for working demo of the query.

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. And what about the case if I wouldn't know the values "a", "b" and just wanted to add counters for all the distinct values in the array? Naming the field like countA conditionally according to the value?

Comment: Since you said `'field' is an enum, so I know all the values in advance and can give names to the counters.` It should be easy. you can add all the counts everytime, or as per your need. Also Please upvote and mark my answer as correct answer. It helps others and also motivates me to keep answering and helping more and more. Thanks!